Codeigniter 4 extend core class process clarification
An attempt has been made to extend the Codeigniter framework Session class and override function get, instead of replacing the whole Session class /  library. This was by following the guide at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/core_classes.html#extending-core-classes
Steps taken:

A new class has been created at app/Libraries/Session.php

Points of note in this file

Added a new namespace: namespace App\Libraries;.
Pulled in the Codeigniter framework Session class: use CodeIgniter\Session\Session as BaseSession;.
Extended this class in the function head class Session extends BaseSession.
Called the parent constructor (not sure if this is required):

public function __construct()  { parent::__construct($this->driver, $this->config);}


Created a function with the same name public function get to override the framework version.


As suggested via https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/core_classes.html#extending-core-classes went to the previous section on the same page https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/core_classes.html#replacing-core-classes and performed the steps as below:

Ensured the Autoload.php could find the namespace App\Libraries (confirmed via php spark namespaces).
An assumption has been made the interface will be implemented by extending the parent class, that implements the interface.
It’s not clear what is meant by and modify the appropriate Service to load your class in place of the core class.

As adding the below to app/Config/Services.php didn’t appear to do anything, another assuption was made that a new Services.php file might need to be created at app/Libraries/Config/Services.php (see below also) - as per https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/core_classes.html#replacing-core-classes;  however it’s not clear if the content of the class(es) is correct.







<?php

// app/Config/Services.php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService;

class Services extends BaseService
{
    public static function get($getShared = true)
    {
        if ($getShared) {
            return static::getSharedInstance('get');
        }
        return new \App\Libraries\Session();
    }
}

<?php

// app/Libraries/Config/Services.php

namespace Libraries\Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService;

class Services extends BaseService
{
    public static function get($getShared = true)
    {
        if ($getShared) {
            return static::getSharedInstance('get');
        }
        return new \App\Libraries\Session();
    }
}


The file located at vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Config/Services.php has not been modified.
var_dump('Session_get');die; has been added to  app/Libraries/Session.php but is not being hit.

Can anyone possibly assist here please?!

Eventually solved here https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=90600
